# Printing a dictionary in Swift different from Objective-C. How to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Printing in Swift 3.0:

[image: Printing in Swift 3.0]

Printing the same in Objective-C:

[image: Printing the same in Objective-C]

Objective-C print is more readable compared to Swift.
Can someone please educate me here ?

Comment: Could you add the dictionary as a code snippet?

Comment: How are you printing the dictionary?

Comment: Also, which version of Xcode are you using? I'm unable to reproduce the Swift result.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Dictionary` into an `NSDictionary` inside the print statement for the Objective-C result:

```
let dict: Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any> = ["key1": "value", "key2": [1, 2, 3]]
print(NSDictionary(dictionary: dict))
```

Which looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, what do need to do is: instead of using `print()` for logging, you should use `dump()`.

For example:

```
let  myDict = ["Foo": "bar", "key": "value"]

print(myDict) // ["Foo": "bar", "key": "value"]
debugPrint(myDict) // ["Foo": "bar", "key": "value"]

dump(myDict)
/*
 ▿ 2 key/value pairs
 ▿ (2 elements)
 - .0: "Foo"
 - .1: "bar"
 ▿ (2 elements)
 - .0: "key"
 - .1: "value"
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `dump` to get your output. Here is a comparison:

```
let dict = ["responseHeader" : [ "QTTime" : 0, "params" : [1, 2, 3]]]
dump(dict) // Outline view
print(dict) // Swift literal view
print(NSDictionary(dictionary: dict)) // Objective-C view
```

The `dump` gives:

```
▿ 2 key/value pairs
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - .0: "Foo"
    - .1: "bar"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - .0: "key"
    - .1: "value"
▿ 1 key/value pair
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - .0: "responseHeader"
    ▿ .1: 2 key/value pairs
      ▿ (2 elements)
        - .0: "QTTime"
        - .1: 0
      ▿ (2 elements)
        - .0: "params"
        ▿ .1: 3 elements
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
```

The `print` gives:

```
["responseHeader": ["QTTime": 0, "params": [1, 2, 3]]]
```

And the cast to `NSDictionary` & `print` gives:

```
{
    responseHeader =     {
        QTTime = 0;
        params =         (
            1,
            2,
            3
        );
    };
}
```

More more fun try `dump(NSDictionary(dictionary: dict))`...

HTH